# Problema em evento de download no "href"

Tags: php, arquivo

Estou com um problema onde preciso encontrar um arquivo no servidor `Linux` com o nome do valor do `<a href>` e realizar o download dele quando clicarem no link.

o caminho do arquivo é `/var/www/html/ligacoes` (aí tem várias pastas e dentro das pastas estão os arquivos, exemplo `/var/www/html/ligacoes/interno/2014/01/30/1391088944.2621-11_35_44-4002-1006.WAV`

Comment: E qual exatamente é o problema? Dá página de erro? Arquivo não encontrado? Abre no browser em vez de baixar?

Comment: Eu tenho um sistema em php, nele traz uma tabela que uma das colunas é vários ID que ao clicar nele, ele baixe um arquivo referente ao ID. O arquivo está em um servidor Linux CentOS

Comment: Você sabe o caminho do arquivo no servidor? Ele é acessível ao servidor web? Por favor use o link de [edit] acima para incluir essas informações na própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solução listando arquivos por ID de uma tabela

Imagino que você tenha uma tabela ou uma forma de fazer um *de/para* do ID do arquivo para o seu respectivo caminho (*path*).

Vamos supor que você tenha a tabela com os campos `ID` e `CAMINHO`, assim:

```
ID   NOME
1    /arquivos/planilha.xls
2    /arquivos/documento.pdf
```

E na página você tenha consiga listar os arquivos assim:

```html
<a href="download.php?id=1">planilha.xls</a>
<a href="download.php?id=2">documento</a>
```

Então, no script `download.php` você precisa fazer uma lógica assim:

```php
$id_arquivo = $_GET['id'];
$caminho = recuperaCaminhoPorId($id_arquivo); //implementar esta função em algum lugar
readfile($caminho); //lê o arquivo e manda para o usuário
```

Obviamente é bom você fazer alguns tratamentos, como para quando o script não receber nenhum parâmetro ou não encontrar o ID no banco de dados.

Veja a [documentação da função `readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php).

Se quiser forçar o download de arquivos que por padrão seriam abertos no navegador (HTML, texto, imagem, etc.), pode colocar também cabeçalhos, como:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($caminho));
```

Note que os cabeçalhos precisam ser definidos antes de escrever o arquivo, ou seja, antes de chamar a função `readfile();`.

## Solução com link direto para o arquivo

Após ver a atualização da pergunta, ficou claro que os arquivos para download estão em uma pasta disponíveis no servidor HTTP.

Para disponibilizar o arquivo, você pode criar um link com o caminho relativo à raiz do servidor.

```html
<a href="/interno/2014/01/30/1391088944.2621-11_35_44-4002-1006.WAV">Download</a>
```

Se quiser listar os arquivos de uma pasta usando PHP e criar os links automaticamente, pode usar a função `scandir()` do PHP para listar os arquivos e fazer um `for` para imprimir os links.

Exemplo:

```php
$files = scandir($dir);
$basedir = '/var/www/html'; 
foreach($files as $f) {
    if($f != '.' && $f != '..') {
        echo '<a href="' . str_replace($basedir,'',$f) . '">'
            . basename($f) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Esta é apenas uma ideia simples que você pode adaptar para sua necessidade.

Comment: ali para procurar o arquivo que estou com problemas também, como posso fazer para localizar este arquivo sendo que não tenho uma pasta fixa?

Comment: @HaoneNakano Se você não tem um banco de dados e o arquivo está dentro de um diretório visível do servidor, como parece ser o caso após ver sua atualização, então você só precisa gerar um link direto. Vou atualizar a resposta para refletir isso.

Comment: @HaoneNakano Resposta atualizada!

Comment: eu sou um pouco leigo, gostaria de saber o que por na variavel $dir.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito a pergunta, mas para buscar um arquivo em um servidor linux, você pode usar ack/grep. Instale o package, se for ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ack-grep
```

E para procurar o arquivo você pode usar:

```
$ ack nome_do_arquivo.txt ~/
```

Sendo o segundo parâmetro "~/" o diretório a partir de onde você quer fazer a busca.

E para criar um link para download desse arquivo, você precisa colocar ele em uma pasta que tenha permissões de acesso via web. Um exemplo simples seria a pasta www do Apache.

Comment: Não sei pq deram voto negativo pra essa resposta... É a única que realmente aborda a parte de `encontrar um arquivo no servidor` que o OP perguntou. Vou dar upvote pra compensar.
Mas concordo que esta resposta está incompleta. O @ElvisMoreira deveria ter comentado sobre como executar o `ack nome_do_arquivo.txt ~/` a partir do PHP, com por exemplo exec(), passthru(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Para que um arquivo seja acessado através de um link, você precisa mandar o caminho correto para ele, segue exemplo.

Você informou que o site se encontra em `/var/www/html/ligacoes`, provavelmente você acessa pelo navegador pela url `http://localhost/ligacoes`, seguindo seu exemplo acima, o arquivo `/var/www/html/ligacoes/interno/2014/01/30/1391088944.2621-11_35_44-4002-1006.WAV` pode ser acessado de duas maneiras:

```
<!-- Link Relativo -->
<a href="/interno/2014/01/30/1391088944.2621-11_35_44-4002-1006.WAV">Baixar</a>
<!-- Link Absoluto -->
<a href="http://localhost/ligacoes/interno/2014/01/30/1391088944.2621-11_35_44-4002-1006.WAV">Baixar</a>
```

Espero ter respondido a sua pergunta!

Comment: mas e quando não tenho um caminho fixo como no exemplo que você passou?

Comment: Você irá precisar saber qual é o caminho, sendo ele gravado no banco (o path inteiro) ou alguma lógica, como por exemplo os arquivos estarem em alguma pasta específica e vc identifica eles com o id da tabela, existe inumeras lógicas e vc terá que saber qual é para resolver seu problema. Mas se vc tiver vários arquivos e nao sabe como identifca-los com sua respectiva linha no banco, é praticamente imposível sem uma lógica pre definida!